# Reading Spaces from a Char Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I am trying to make a program that will convert a `String` to `Binary`. To do that I converted the User Input to `char` array. Using `for` loops to read the characters in the `char` array one by one.

My Problem is how can I read spaces from the `char` Array. Here's my code.

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < UserInput.length() ; i++) {
    char c = UserInput.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isLetter(c)){
            System.out.print ("letter");
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(c)){
            System.out.print ("number");
        }
        else if (c== " "){
            System.out.print ("space");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ("Special Char");
        }
    }
```

The Errors shows bad operand types for binary operator `'=='else if ((c) == " ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare Character with a String.
That's why the error.
Try using

> Character.isSpaceChar(c)

Hope this works for you.

Comment: `isSpaceChar` considers more types of whitespace than just the basic space (ASCII 0x20, Unicode U+0020), given the given code that might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

`c` is of type character and you're trying to compare it to `" "` which is of type string, if you want to check if `c` is a space you should compare it to `' '` which is also of type character.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a string with array.

One space character is represented by ' ' and not " "

Just change this,

```
if (c== " ")
```

to

```
if (c== ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

While

```
if(c==' ')
```

would work for the standard whitespace character there are actually multiple different types of whitespaces like non-breaking-spaces for example.

But just like for letters and digits there already exists a function in Character to check if a character is any of those whitespaces:

```
if(Character.isWhitespace(c))
```